# Why is a ControllerOption Filter being called for non-controller endpoints in my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, umbraco

I am working on a large site built on Umbraco but with a lot of custom code - I don't think this is an Umbraco-specific problem.

The code has a set of API controllers all marked up with `[ApiController]` attributes.

In my Startup `ConfigureServices` method I have the following:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     // other stuff that I assume is not relevant in this case.
     services.AddControllers(controllerOptions => {
            controllerOptions.Filters.Add<JwtAuthorisationFilter>();
            });
 }
```

When I run my code in production mode, all the Javascript and CSS files are minified so instead of `/umbraco/js/abc.js` they become something like `/umbraco/js/abc.js.AV00AF1234D2`.

My problem is that for some reason these files are being passed through to my `JwtAuthorisationFilter` even though that is added through `AddControllers` and they obviously don't have any ApiController attributes.

The ideal behaviour would be for them to be passed straight to the client rather than going through the filter stack at all.

Why are these minified static files being treated as controller endpoints and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you please share a [mre] or at least `Configure` method?

Comment: I can't see anything relevant in `Configure` it's largely a default Umbraco configuration. Do you think it could be something in the `app.WithEndpoints()` call?

Comment: My guess would be some order inconsistency in the middleware pipelines.

Comment: In that case I am mistaken, this _is_ an Umbraco-specific problem.